# Solving an ODE with complex coefficients in python

Tags: python

I have a system of coupled ODEs with complex coefficients. I have figured out how to numerically solve a system with real values coefficients, for example,

```
u0' = u1

u1' = u0
```

To do this I use scipy.integrate.odeint class as follows,

```
def vectorfield(w,t):
    u0,u1 = w

    #create f = [x1',y1',...]

    f = [u1, u0]
    return f

wsol = odeint(vectorfield, w0, t)
```

where `w0` is the initial value of w for example:
`w0 = [1,1]`

**However** now I need to solve a system with **complex** coefficients, say

```
u0' = i*u1
u1' = i*u0
```

However, when I tried using the same method as I did for the real valued coefficients, I don't get any complex numbers in the result, only real valued answers at each time step. **How should I change the above code to account for complex coefficients?**

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**, here is my entire code for an example:

```
#coupled differential equations
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.integrate import ode
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from scipy import eye



# Setting initital conditions


u_initial = [1,1]


def vectorfield(w,t):

    u0,u1 = w


    #create f = [x1',y1',...]

    f = [1j*u1*u1.conjugate()+u0,1j*u0*u0.conjugate()+u1]
    return f

abserr = 1.0e-8
relerr = 1.0e-6

stoptime = 10
numpoints = 300

t = [stoptime * float(i) / (numpoints - 1) for i in range(numpoints)]


w0 = u_initial #set initial conditions

wsol = odeint(vectorfield, w0, t,
          atol=abserr, rtol=relerr)
```

Comment: please make a complete MWE...and you have to specify which python modules you want to use or want to avoid. You are using scipy, but three is something called fypi for solving ODEs/PDEs.

Comment: @user69453, what is a MWE?

Comment: Also it seems that fypi is for PDEs. I am only interested in ODEs at the moment.

Comment: Complex coeffients don't necessarily mean complex solutions.

Comment: An example I can copy and paste and just look at your problem without having to guess half of your code ;) http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge but I know I should be getting complex solutions. Also when I try make the initial values complex, it gives the error: can't convert complex to float